# "R cannot be resolved to a variable" android error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have freshly installed eclipse 3.8 and android sdk. When I create a new project I get error `R cannot be resolved to a variable` in `MainActivity.java`. `R.java` is missing and instead I have `BuildConfig.java` in gen folder. Based on suggestions given on similar questions I tried followings but no success.

1. Reinstalled ADT
2. Cleaned the project
3. Restart eclipse

Kindly help.

Comment: Has one of your xml files an error? If so, R will not be generated.

Comment: Is there an R.java in your project folder?  this can help tell us whether the file isnt there or whether it is there and you are having a pointing proplem to it.

Comment: same problem here, errors in your xml , even appmanifest file and R is not generated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, XML files may be the culprit, but also make sure you have an import statement at the top of your file for it as well. **Edit** here is the typical beginning of a java file, you need the R import where my comment is

```
package your.package.name;

import your.package.name.R;    // make sure you have this line
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
```

Comment: `xml` files r not showing any error, although they do not have that import statement.

Comment: That statement needs to go at the top of the .java code files that you want to reference R, not the XML file

Comment: java file has `package com.thenewbos.am;` at the top\

Comment: It needs to be in the imports section, I will edit the answer

Comment: I added `import com.thenewbos.am.R;`. It was not there. But this also gives error `the import cannot be resolved`. Instead of `R.java`, I have `BuildConfig.java` file.

Comment: Then I think the others are correct, it is more likely that something is stopping R.Java from being generated correctly.  It is hard to tell what that is without more information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23801/discussion-between-ashni-goyal-and-mjmarsh)

Comment: sorry, my corporate firewall blocks SO chat :/

Answer (score 0):

Verify the syntax on your XML files. The problem may not be in MainActivity.java. If there's an error on any of your XML files the class R won't be generated.

Comment: Look at the "Errors" view on Eclipse. Is there any errors? Sometimes Eclipse doesn't show the "red cross" on the class

Comment: Also, check your Manifest file to see if it's not referencing anything that doesn't exist on your project anymore, in case you excluded some artifact.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse, remove the R class import in your class and press 
`CTRL + SHIFT + O`, it will automatically import your classes.
If it proposes your move than one R class, select the one from your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error in your XML file then R.java will not be generated. Try cleaning your project and look for any signs of errors on your XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The R.Java was not generated(in the gen folder). There was no error in the xml file. The issue was that I did not update the sdk completely. In the SDK manager we need to install the package whenever the "install package" button is enabled and close and open the sdk manager to check for updates. Close and reopen eclipse and check for updates in eclipse also.

Answer (score 0):

See this question [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?lq=1), probably help you if you recently installed the ADT