# Android R cannot be resolved in Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**DatabaseConnect** is the name of the Android Application Project that has been created in Eclipse in Ubuntu Platform.

One of the java file Inside **DatabaseConnect->src->co.package.datewithme** is shown Below.

```
  package com.example.datewithme;


  import android.app.Activity; 
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.text.InputType; 
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageView; 
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Login extends Activity{
 Intent i=null;
 ImageView im=null;
 EditText tv1,tv4;
 boolean flag=false;
 SQLiteDatabase db=null;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show_hide2);
    tv1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone2);
    tv4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password2);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 // db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,mobile_no varchar,email_id varchar,password varchar,flag varchar)");

    im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(flag==false)
            {
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.hide);
                tv4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                flag=true;
            }
            else
            {
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.show);
                tv4.setInputType(129);
                flag=false;

            }
        }
    });
  }

   public void action(View v)
   {
     switch(v.getId())
     {
    case R.id.signin2: 
    i=new Intent(this,Signin.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 500);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom); 
    finish();
    break;
  case R.id.start:
    String mobile_no=tv1.getText().toString();
    String password=tv4.getText().toString();
    if(mobile_no==null||mobile_no==""||mobile_no.length()<10)
    {
        show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
    }
    else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
    {
        show("Please Enter Correct Password.");
    }
    else
    {       
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from login where mobile_no='"+mobile_no+"' and password='"+password+"'",null);   
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getCount()>0)
        {
        i=new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,500);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 
        db.close();
        finish();
        }
        else
            show("Wrong Password or Mobile number.");

    }
    break;
    }
       }
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
  } 

 public void show(String str)
 {
 Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
 }

}
```

The error message generated is **R cannot be resolved to a variable**.But i have **R.java** file in my Project **DatabaseConnect->gen->com.example.Databaseconnect->BuilConfig.java,R.java.**

The ScreenShot is shown below.
[image]

I Searched all the possibilities for the solution by going through these links.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615477/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-new-android-project)

But din't got the proper solution.

I came to know the naming convention got some errors like **DatabaseConnect** and **Datewithme.** So i kept the same name to both and then clean and run the project but after that its that its taking previous name itself.

An help is appreciated

Comment: you will need to import project R file `<Project_Package_Name>.R` or trying using `CTRL+SHIFT+O`

Comment: frist u see the consol and say what in consol

Comment: first remove jar mismatch error.. check the build path

Answer (score 1):

Here are some TroubleShooting Steps for this issue.First you may clean the project, then run the project. If this does not work then follow the following links:

Here is the best way to solve this problem:[Android Development- Where is my R.Java file?](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/)
1.[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)
2.[R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592806/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)
3.[R cannot be resolved to a variable -- mailing list entry](http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-t52607.html)
4.[Fixed: R cannot be resolved to a variable](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/fixed-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably It happens when you have an `error` in any of your xml files under `res` folder

**You should check:**

all of your `xml` files under `res` folder fix errors like for example (under drawable folder you have not include icon.png and you are using it as @drawable/icon). When you will check and fix all errors in xml files then Build your project or clean it.

Hope you will understand my words.