# I have updated Android SDK to rev. 22 yesterday and there is no apkbuilder in tools

Tags: android, build, apk

I have checked with my friend who has Android SDK tools version 21, the `apkbuilder` is there. I have updated the Android SDK tools to version 22 and I can't find `apkbuilder` anymore.

So it seems that the Andorid SDK tool has replace the `apkbuilder` with something else?
How can I make ant build.xml without apkbuilder?
Is there some other way to build the unsigned apk for Android?

Answer (score 9):

You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570).

> After updating to SDK Tools to rev. 22 for the first time, you may
>   need to relaunch Android SDK Manager again and install a new item:
>   **Android SDK Build-tools**. [image]
>
> After installing this, clean your projects and rebuild.

Comment: Did you checked? Build-tools do not include apkbuilder.

Comment: I have done this。 And build.xml is exists and  i want to find the instead  tool of apkbuilder.How the sdk tool ver.22 build apk?without apkbuilder?

Comment: Also perform "android update project -p ." in your project directory. This will update your build.xml.

Comment: The apkbuilder/apkbuilder.bat wrappers around "com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain" no longer exit in rev 22.

Comment: I hope to fix my rebuild problem after updating it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In old version of AndroidSDK, the apkbuilder is just like a shell, actually it calls:
${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/sdklib.jar

So, if you deep into the root of apkbuilder, you can finder there are two ways to invoke it:

1. from ant
   There is an ant-extend lib under:
   ${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar
   So, you can invoke it like this:

   ```
   <path id="android.antlibs">
       <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar" />
   </path>

   <!-- Custom tasks -->
   <taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />

   <apkbuilder
           outfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
           resourcefile="${resource.package.file.name}"
           apkfilepath="${out.packaged.file}"
           debugpackaging="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
           debugsigning="${build.is.signing.debug}"
           verbose="${verbose}"
           hascode="${manifest.hasCode}"
           previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}/${build.last.is.signing.debug}"
           buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}/${build.is.signing.debug}">
       <dex path="${intermediate.dex.file}"/>
       <sourcefolder path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
       <jarfile refid="project.all.jars.path" />
       <nativefolder path="${native.libs.absolute.dir}" />
       <nativefolder refid="project.library.native.folder.path" />
       <extra-jars/>
   </apkbuilder>
   ```
2. for script or other development
   You can use ${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/sdklib.jar, the apkbuilder was included in.
   Take a look at apkbuild.bat in previous version, at the end of the file:

   ```
   set jarfile=sdklib.jar
   set frameworkdir=

   if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
       set frameworkdir=lib\

   if exist %frameworkdir%%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
       set frameworkdir=..\framework\

   :JarFileOk

   set jarpath=%frameworkdir%%jarfile%

   call %java_exe% -classpath %jarpath% com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain %*
   ```

Comment: This is the only answer that explains how to invoke ApkBuilder now.

Answer (score 5):

You could copy an apkbuilder.bat to your path_to_sdk_home/tools/, then continue you build.
I found a copy [here](https://github.com/ACSOP/android_sdk/blob/master/apkbuilder/etc/apkbuilder.bat), and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK notes for rev.22 state:

> Changed the structure of the SDK by adding a new build tool SDK
>   Component, which is based on the existing platform-tools component.
>   This change decouples the build tools versions from the IDE versions,
>   allowing updates to the tools without requiring an IDE update.

One of the temporary options is to roll back your SDK tools back to rev.21 where apkbuilder existed. You can do that by backing up tools folder (e.g. rename it to tools_22) and downloading previous tools from rev.21: dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20-windows.zip, unpack it to your SDK and it will work like before.

Comment: THX.Iwant to find a way to edit my build.xml to fit the new version tool .Or should i change builder to gradle or sth else?

Comment: In the case that will not roll back my sdk tool verison 21?In fact i want to know how build the apk in tools version 22?The  sugest way?

Comment: I know only of this solution. Maybe someone else knows a better way around rev.22

Answer (score 1):

Doing a bit of research around this, it seems APKBuilder.bat, although deprecated, can still be used but will no longer be supported/enhanced. [[1](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/81941/error-candroid-sdktoolsapkbuilderbat)]

The new com.android.sdklib.build.APKBuilder Java class should now be used [[2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/e162064a7b5db1eecec34271bc7e2a4296181ea6/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/build/ApkBuilder.java)] as this is what will be developed, going forward.

Comment: See liuyong's answer for a link to the bat.

Comment: It indeed appears as if the script has been removed. For now, using an old version works because the command line interface still exists as part of the Java class, though I wouldn't be surprised if that goes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way but i don't very sure of it. I saw a ant directory in tools directory and found a build.xml  contains the new way to build apk. I also saw ant_task.jar in the tools/lib directory.When i unzip the jar i fount some classes like Apk ApkBuilderTask.class CheckEnvTask.class and so on... So i think the way is be changed to build apk with the ant Task,i 'll try to use the template to build the apk ,and if it works i will post the solution here.
thanks!

Comment: You can recreate your project build.xml to use the new method but running "android update project -p ." in your project directory.