# Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working

Tags: android-studio

I installed android studio.. it was working fine. Now all the sudden, none of the auto complete features are working.. I can type anything anywhere no variable checking, no help with functions or checking anything. I can still compile the project and I get errors when that happens.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Comment: Can be linked to kotlin gradle version , refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68649643/14784590

Answer (score 267):

**#1** From <kbd>Build</kbd> menu (of your Android Studio), click <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd> option.

**#2** Then once rebuild completes, go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart...</kbd> and Click on <kbd>Invalidate an Restart</kbd> button.

[image]

[image]

This really works for me.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61844#c4

> **#1** Rebuild is required, because Android-Studio does simply rely solely on Gradle's build-result (without static-analysis support, at least at time of writing, 2022).
>
> **#2** Clearing cache is required, because the *previous* build-result (before above rebuild) may be indexed, which makes Android Studio ignore latest Gradle build-result
> (this is a very good speed optimization, but a very bad Developer-experience as well).
>
> There can sometimes be other reasons too, which is why there are many other answers posted here.

Comment: This works. You have to wait for the "indexing" process to finish. By the way, what's up with SO's answer sorting? This is clearly the best answer but it is below several bad copies of the power save mode answer (which doesn't work).

Comment: no longer working - A.S. 3.1.3 has suddenly stopped giving suggestions when editing XML !

Comment: If this does not work for you, try manually deleting the caches: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388983/1689222). This helped in my case.

Comment: Can confirm. This solution worked on Android Studio 4.1.3

Comment: Yes, it will work after restart only for a short time. and again It will be gone. I have to restart every 15min to work with suggestions.

Comment: Can confirm it also helps if you have automaticly hiding suggessions issue.

Comment: In my case it's not working. AS just suddenly [w/o any update etc] stopped suggesting code ...

Comment: This fix sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. This time it wasn't working, **but helped updating AndroidStudio**.

Answer (score 128):

You can also check if **Power Save Mode** on **File** menu is disabled.

Comment: For me disabling power-save mode did the trick ! Thanks. For others Power Save Mode mode can be disabled from File->Power Save Mode

Comment: After much googling, this finally worked for me, but I had to exit and restart Android Studio before it started working.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I could disable Power Save only after unplugging and plugging in again my laptop

Comment: This was it!!!!

Answer (score 74):

Originally use:

```
compileSdkVersion 32
targetSdkVersion 32
```

And an update to 33 appeared, I updated it and the suggestions in the XML no longer appeared, I went back to 32 and now the suggestions appeared.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in both android studio chipmunk and IntelliJ as well. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Same problem, this is weirder than combing a bald man. any solution?

Comment: same thing happens to me, reverted back to 32 and voila,  
I guess with 33 we have to use latest android studio and invoke update migration

Comment: I have the same problem, will there be a solution to be able to use version 33 without affecting the autocomplement of the xml?

Comment: After updating to 33, suggestions not coming. and if update to 32 then building error comes.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! This is the only one working solution for me

Comment: Thanks this change solved my problem. But I wonder what could be the reason, 33 is trying to tell us not to use XML anymore, use Jetpack compose?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. this is so beneath the quality of Google products.

Comment: Unfortunately works. ;D

Answer (score 64):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to `C:\Users\UserName\.android` and rename the folder:

   - `build-cache` to `build-cache_old`
3. Go to `C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio3.x\system`
   OR (*for Android studio 4 and Higher*) go to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.x`
   and rename these folders:

   - `caches` to `caches_old`
   - `compiler` to `compiler_old`
   - `compile-server` to `compile-server_old`
   - `conversion` to `conversion_old`
   - `external_build_system` to `external_build_system_old`
   - `frameworks` to `frameworks_old`
   - `gradle` to `gradle_old`
   - `resource_folder_cache` to `resource_folder_cache_old`
4. Open Android Studio and open your project again.

Comment: Works like a charm! "Invalidate and Restart" didn't work for me. By the way, for newer versions of Android Studio, the AndroidStudio folder is located at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: Thank you man, it's really work! Invalidate + restart was not enough, and I spend ~2 hour for find a solution. After renaming/removing this folders and opening project IDE starts indexing and everything become workable!

Comment: this is the only working solution on SO for this problem.

Comment: I closed Studio and deleted all folders named AndroidStudio in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\ fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Help! There is no `gradle` nor a `resource_folder_cache` in that location! (`C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2`) Where could they be?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård - for me it worked without deleting those folders

Comment: Linux users can find this folder under HOME/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3 (make sure you turn on show hidden files)

Answer (score 34):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to c_users_path_on_windows/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/
3. Delete the `cache` folder
4. Start Android Studio

   This works for me.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.

Comment: Thank you brother!!! After so many solutions this finally worked.

Comment: Save my time Thanks Stuck with 2 Hrs again and Restarting Android Studio Finally its fixed

Comment: I'm actually adding a cron job to delete this folder every morning - thanks.  I also disabled some inspections that didn't make sense for my project

Comment: I can't find this path !

Answer (score 17):

Most of the times i have seen that the problem is that `Power Save Mode` is enabled, to disable go to `Current inspection profile` (lower right corner in `Android Studio`).

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I have not run into this problem personally, but try checking the following settings (`File` -> `Settings` or `Alt+F7`):

**Project Settings [name]**
`Inspections` - ensure that `Android` and `Android Lint` is checked, or alternately just set it back to default using the dropdown box at the top.

**IDE Settings**
`Editor` -> `Code Completion` - ensure the `Autopopup code completion` is checked (and check the rest of the settings based on your preference.

Answer (score 12):

Uncheck "Power Save Mode" in "File" tab

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem where none of the other solutions worked.

Closing Android Studio and then deleting the .idea and build folders resolved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

If nothing works (like happened with me ) go to your user profile in windows at %userprofile% . You will find folders there (hidden) named with the version of the android studio you are using and prefixed with a dot.

like .AndroidStudio3.1. Just delete that .

Comment: This will delete all the configurations that you have setup for android studio

Answer (score 7):

**Solution**: Try disabling **"File -> Power Save Mode"** in **Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14 - Mac OS X**

On windows, the option can be at some other place.

---

I had the same problem then I recalled that while exploring the new android studio, I switched on the **"File -> Power Save Mode"** to see what it does?

I disabled the power save mode and all those intelligent features were back.

It turned out that in Power Save Mode, Android Studio switches off the modules responsible for features like [Smart Code Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_completion.html) and [Code Analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_analysis.html).

Answer (score 7):

For Artic Fox 2020|3.1 Version: Auto Complete Suggestion Problem.

Please Follow the Following Steps:

Close Android Studio

Locate caches folder in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
and Delete it.
Open Android Studio Again.

Check your Android studio version and Target that version folder at below location
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Google

Note : AppData folder is Hidden in Windows

This Solution also works if android studio mess up with xml files and java code. Don't! modify your code otherwise IDE won't able to change it to default. If you see such messy code just follow above steps and your code will be fine again.

Answer (score 6):

Disable **Power Save Mode** and **Invalidate Cache and Restart**.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers solved my issue , the thing that solved my issue is select file > Manage ide > restore defaults , i don't know what was the reason exactly but i was thinking of multiple plugins conflict with each others

Answer (score 5):

***It's Working***

*Disable Power Save Mode*

Untick Power Save Mode Option **::** 
File -> Power Save Mode

Answer (score 4):

Just remove all the folders named `AndroidStudioPreview`

**On Windows:**

Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

`[SYSDRIVE]:\Users[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe)`

In this folder there should be a folder called `.AndroidStudioPreview`

**On Mac OS X**

Remove these files:

`~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview 
 ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview 
 ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioPreview 
 ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview`

Answer (score 4):

There is a power saver mode in android studio if accidentally you click on that it will disable code analysis which will reduce the battery consumption and performance will also increase but it will not detect any errors and do auto complete operations.

To disable power saver mode

```
- Go to File Menu of Studio
- Uncheck The Power Saver Mode
```

In your IDE code analysis will be shown using an eye symbol at the right corner of your android studio.

```
If Green means it is enabled and there is no error in your code.
If Red Means It is enabled but there are few errors in your code.
If It is white or blur then code analysis is disabled
```

Comment: Green check means there are no errors. Yellow square means there are warnings. Red square means there are errors. White eye means it's in progress. White pause icon means it's waiting on an autocomplete window to close. There's another white icon that means it's in power save mode and is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me.
From menu select:

> File -> Power Save Mode

and make sure it's disabled

Answer (score 3):

There can be several things which cause this.

1. Make sure you've write the correct version in `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion`.
2. Make sure `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` are same.

Other solutions can be:

1. Invalidate caches & restart Android Studio from `File` → `Invalidate Caches / Restarts...`
2. Clean your project from `Build` → `Clean Project`
3. Rebuild project from `Build` → `Rebuild Project`
4. Make project from `Build` → `Make Project` [this process may take some time]

Comment: Where does one check the `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion`? I know it's there in the app/build.gradle file, but nowadays, they don't say the actual numbers... They say only `targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion`...

Comment: Yes, but the question and answer were for native android, not for flutter.

Comment: Ok, but can you please answer the question where I can check those versions in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to check for IDE errors by clicking the button at the bottom right of android studio.

[image]

In my case, there was a bad plugin, and the IDE Fatal Errors window prompted me to uninstall the plugin. (I wish I'd known about this feature before spending half a day invalidating caches, deleting folders, and reinstalling android studio with no luck.)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Go TO Left Side Top File Option]

Go TO Left Side Top **File** Option

Then Click To **Power Save Mode**

[image]

Disable Power Save Mode That Fix This Issue

Comment: if you can't fix this issue you can check your  TargetSDK is 33 that's why you face this issue  By You need to change it to Target SDK32

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I switch keyboard language to English, the auto complete works again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a library project included, make sure the library has the dependencies in `build.gradle` listed using [the `api` configuration, not the `implementation` configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).
Also make sure that the project that includes the library has all the dependencies listed (using the `implementation` configuration is fine here).

Comment: It still doesn't work. I included a custom view in xml file. The attributes(custom or default), doesn't auto complete. Even dimens or string file referencing also doesn't work for only that view.

Answer (score 1):

```
'The file size (2561270 bytes) exceeds configured limit (2560000 bytes). Code insight features are not available.'
```

Had this issue for days with none of these proposed solutions working before eventually getting this message in yellow under the tabs after adding a line of code. Removing the line of code eliminated the message but not the issue. There appears to be a code size window where you lose insight features but don't get this message, at least for me. Once you go over a certain point the message finally pops up. The suggested solution in a different thread for this issue was to edit 'Help/Edit Custom Properties' to increase the configured limit, but just opening this brought up a dialogue asking if I wanted to create an 'idea.properties' folder so I decided not to risk that approach over eventually cutting the file size.

Answer (score 1):

if the autocomplete isn't working for you in Android Studio, just press File and uncheck the Power save mode, it should work fine after that.
if power save mode is already unchecked then first check then uncheck them.

Comment: You can find power save in file -> Power Save Mode

Answer (score 1):

If sometimes this problem can occur if you misspelled a file extension or make a file without adding an extension.
Check you have added the file extension correctly.

I think that answer may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mac and suddenly the code completion (^space) not working. There are no errors. Turned out the **android studio's shortcut was conflicted with system's shortcut**. I don't know why it suddenly happen because it was fine before, maybe there was an update on my Mac.

See below setting for the conflicting shortcut
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Invalidate caches/Restart from File in Menu Bar from android studio.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\ just delete caches folder and restart android studio. after deleting this caches folder my problem was solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, If you still not getting Syntax highlighting or code completion, just press on `File -> Repair IDE`. That's it.

I had resolved this issue on `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1`

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I misspelled the word `kotlin` when renaming the fully-qualified name of one of my modules.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the solutions posted here on Giraffe (the power save tip as well) and none of them did work. I have also updated all the other AS components (SDK tools and similar) but without any luck. I have even deleted Gradle's build cache folder (as that helped me before with other weird errors), but no success either. I have restarted AS and the PC several times during this time (and countless deletion of AS folders or subfolders in the users path, idea folders, and invalidated caches/cleaned/rebuilt/make the project).

**At the end, I have disabled Flutter, Dart, and some other plugins that I had and it finally started working.**

**Note:** The AS did not complain that any plugin is misbehaving.

It seems that some plugin was not compatible with the newer versions of AS (even though they have been updated as well). Before disabling the plugins, all projects and auto-completion worked well on Electric Eel, but none worked with Giraffe or even Hedgehog RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter with this problem while adding a kotlin library into my project on mac. Changing macbook language to english solved this problem. I also had some weird problems with auto-generated databinding codes, those are also solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Close Android Studio**

Go to

`C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.android`

and rename the following folder to:

`build-cache to build-cache_old`

then Go to (Android studio lower then version 4)

`C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.x\system`

OR (Android studio 4 and Higher) Go to

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.x`

or

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2`

depending on your version and rename these folders:

```
caches to caches_old

compiler to compiler_old

compile-server to compile-server_old

conversion to conversion_old

external_build_system to external_build_system_old

frameworks to frameworks_old

gradle to gradle_old (if exists)

resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache_old (if exists)
```

**Open Android Studio again and the autosuggsion will be fixed.**

and You can also check if Power Save Mode is disabled or not from the File menu.

Comment: please explain the logic behind renaming files instead of deleting them straight away. Because either way, android studio will automatically generate these files again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Open folder "`%UserName% \ .AndroidStudio %version%\ system`"
3. Delete folder "`caches`".

It is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First Step : Restart your android studio by this way:

File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate And Restart

if problem still exists then you should use compileSdk And targetSdk 33

*note : in sdk 33 google want push you to use jetpack compose and auto comp no longer support...

Comment: "in sdk 33 google want push you to use jetpack compose and auto comp no longer support" this is baseless. what does it have to do with xml autocomplete?! there is a bug in api 33 and Chipmunk version of android studiu; if you update to latest android studio this bug is fixed.

Comment: yes that ' true google fixed it in newest update.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue tracker. I was using Android Studio Chipmunk and I had to update it to Dolphin. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885.
I hope it helps

Comment: this is correct for api 33. worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate caches and restart did not work for me. Looks like this is a known issue and the solution is to update to the latest stable Android studio version (Dolphin 2021.3.1). After update everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the hints from this topic and couldn't find solution for that problem, but finally I am leaving here another hint:

**Try to disable Lombok plugin and check if it helps** - for me it worked. Lombok plays in some way with code suggestions and can break this functionality.

(File -> Settings -> Plugins -> uncheck Lombok)

Especially if you use quite latest Android Studio which is incompatible with Lombok plugin anymore  and you installed this plugin by copying it to 'plugins' folder in Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

i have this problem many times until now ,i suggest thees approach :

1-as said **check power saveing mode**

2-create **new project** with same application id and package name and **copy all source and resource** from older project to new one,

Comment: Recreating a project in this manner is kind of a "WebMD" approach... it's cancer,

Answer (score -1):

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Go to C:/User/[SystemName] and delete .gradle file.
3. Open Android Studio and sync gradle file again.

Answer (score -1):

From menu select:
File->Invalidate Catches/Restart...

than in opened dialog select: "Invalidate and Restart"
and wait to restart android studio.