# Android studio Content Assist not working with Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-studio

This is my Button in Android Studio

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

Now i want to button.setOnClickListener but i cant, the auto completion is not working, and said "Cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener"

Does anybody knows anything about this?

The autocomplete is not working for "setOnClickListener" but i can autocomplete other things

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Comment: sorry i ment to say that the autocomplete is not working for "setOnClickListener" but i can autocomplete other things

Comment: Use this directly : 
`button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    
    }
});`

Comment: I did but i Still get "Cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener" i also get "Cannot resolve symbol v"

Comment: Ty  Shivam Verma, the solution was in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You are not in any method probably you are trying to write that in the class scope. Try writing in onCreate method of your activity or some other method