# Code completion does not work for External Library XML attributes (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am using `Android Studio 1.1 RC 1`.

I've imported an external library into Gradle:

```
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
```

I've added the namespace tag:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

into the parent as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="net.xxx.xxx.ui.activities.Activity"/>
```

I get code completion for the custom views within the library i.e.:

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView />
```

But nothing comes up when I try code completion for the attributes for this view. I have to type all this in manually.

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:completionThreshold="3"
    android:hint="Enter name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    app:floatingLabel="normal"
    app:floatingLabelText="Find xxx"/>
```

Is there a setting or import that I'm missing?

**Helpful Info:**
The attribute file in the library can be found here.
https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. But I have solved it.
Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart
It's an efficient way. You can try.

Source: [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Note: Here are some other approaches too. Have a look.

Comment: This is a much easier solution than reinstalling Android Studio. Thanks heaps!