# Android Studio XML No suggestions for supportor lib

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I add dependence for RecylerView. But when I edit it in xml files is show no suggestions. When edit TextView in xml it works well, what can I do to solve it, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is part of the v7 support library and not in the framework. You do not get suggestions for external libraries.

[Possible duplicate to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921877/code-completion-does-not-work-for-external-library-xml-attributes-android-studi)