# Autocompletion not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Autocompletion is not working in Android Studio.  How do I fix it?

Comment: show me some of your code and your error log in logcat

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working will help you

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to set

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

in AutoCompleteTextView in xml