# Cannot use several code completion in Android Studio on TextView, ListView, etc

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android Studio doesn't give me any suggestion I need (everytime I press CTRL + space). I also can't use the import function (Alt + Enter) to import TextView, ArrayAdapter, ListView, etc.

I appreciate any help.

Here is the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k7Ka.png

Comment: check this, don't knoiw if gonna work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Comment: I've tried it, it didn't work