# Toast not auto-completing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

All of the auto-complete functionality works in Android Studio except for the Toast class for some reason. Not a huge problem since i pretty much only use the

```
Toast.makeText()
```

static function.

However, when I instantiate a toast the auto-complete works.

Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix it? I already tried the 'quick fixes', such as invalidating caches and restarting as well as reopening the project.

Answer (score 0):

Update Android Studio and SDKs that you are working with.

Comment: That's really weird then, especially that it is only Toast. What about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working