# Issues with Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

After recent upgrade to Android Studio 2.3 a lot of issues came up. I am developing in native code/c++ with only a very little Java. I use ndk-build from IDE with Android.mk and Application.mk and only the basic stuff in gradle.build that comes when you start a new project with c++ support (Cmake removed).

1) Intelligent code completion (lookup of methods, classes etc) practically doesn't work at all. When starting studio the first visible page of latest opened source file is "parsed", but that's it. Only basic colouring of commands versus parameters, but no live parsing or code completion while typing. Settings are correct (to my eyes), powers saving mode is disabled and I've invalidate cache many times. Pressing explicitly ctrl+space gives no suggestions found for my code. These issues can be reproduced by completely installing studio from scratch with the ide+sdk package from main site and then opening a project with native code. I have not tested any xml or java code.

2) In addition to above, studio complains about "Can't resolve type xxx" for eg int32_t, android_app, GL-specic commands etc. though they compile ok. Also the editor suddenly complains about incompatible pointer types though they work. And eg. std::string, it complains about the std namespace not recognised though it compiles.

3) I use __android_log_xx functionality and log printing worked to Run-window in previous Studio but not in 2.3 anymore. It is only visible in logcat.

4) Ndk r14 has the bug that 'mips' ABI does not compile if code has empty braces '{}'. But why does building not obey APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a from Application.mk? You have to put eg. ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' into build.gradle.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 5) Neither does 'go to - declaration' work.

Comment: This has been filed as a bug now: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=260154

Comment: Temporary workaround: This has something to do with the ndk-build package. I installed a previous build r13b in a separate directory and pointed to it in the project's local.properties file, invalidated cache with restart and suddenly code completion works again... Thanks to Jean-Baptiste Boin in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033177/how-to-autocomplete-code-with-c-c-in-android-studio-with-android-ndk