# My android studio no longer formats code or predicts which classes I need imported. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio

Previously, when a class was not imported, Android suggested I import them AND used to give resources a special format as in "R.id.***aLayout***". It has suddenly stopped and I am completely stuck, importing all these classes manually will be a real pain.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Comment: check and see if power saver mode is on

Comment: @ankitagrawal how do i do this?

Comment: click on file->power save mode

Comment: @Sevle thanks! You guys just saved my sanity.

Comment: @ankitagrawal thanks!

Comment: did it help if so i will post it as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if `Power Save Mode` is on or off in `Android Studio` .

If it is on turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Open `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` & click on `Invalidate and Restart`

**Note:** Save your project before doing this.

Cheers :)