# Auto-completion doesn't work in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, autocomplete

Auto-completion doesn't work in android studio with XML files. With Java it's okay. I tried many solutions (disable power save mode, invalidate cache...).

What can I do to turn AC on?

Comment: By auto completion do you mean intellisense? If it is so, then there might be some error in the parent view code, that you have. Add you xml code as well. It might help

Comment: the probeme caused in all the files also when i create new file i cant user auto-completion

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397708/3409734

Answer (score 2):

Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

Try this reported issue source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61844#c4

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me.

1. close android studio
2. Go to path/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/ delete caches folder
3. start Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the caches, restarting, and setting things but none of them worked.

I fixed this problem by down the target/compile SDK version from 33 to 30.

**build.gradle > down the targetSdkVersion (33 to 30 in my case) as well as the compileSdkVersion**

this solution works for me even though I have SDK library for API 31,32, and 33