# Android Studio not working properly - cannot access full dropdown options

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm currently learning Android Studio, and am just a beginner, so forgive me if I'm doing something wrong. 
Options are not being displayed in the drop down menu, for example, if I add a new ImageView, the layout_width's dropdown options show both match_constraint and wrap_content - however, match_parent is missing. I have to manually type in match_ parent, upon which it begins working properly.
Also, the autocomplete is not working properly, and it used to work until a couple of days ago. For example, if I wanted findViewById, I just have to search find, and a list of dropdown options would have appeared, from which I can select. That too has gone missing. Any tips?

Comment: so you are not getting suggestions from android studio ?

Comment: tried ctrl+space?

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23761820/7505436) or [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505820/7505436)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Build-->Clean Project
```

then

```
Buil-->Rebuilt Project
```

if it was working fine before
and run the project again