# I can't use ImageView in android studio Gradle 4.7

Tags: android, google-apps-script, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I can't use `ImageView` in android studio gradle 4.7

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_minus" />
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView), check [this](https://cameronstonerblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/imageview-vs-appcompatimageview/) article.

Answer (score 0):

make Image view like that :

```
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
```