# How to fix "No Suggestion" on ctrl+space on xml file android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, autosuggest

I can't get any suggestion from my xml layout file. What must I do to fix the problem?

I have tried to invalidate/restart Android studio, enable and disable, deleting build folder, .idea folder, .iml file, and I have tried to make a new project but the suggestion still not show up.

[image]

I just want to show suggestion like before normally.

[image]
[EDIT]

And every time i select TextView or EditText the element not making layout_width and height automatically.

[image]

**How I Solved It!**

Everybody maybe had a different way of solving this problem. But for me after doing so many experiments, the last thing I do is going to delete configuration setting for Android Studio on "C:\Users\.AndroidStudio" then all fixed for me.

Comment: Most of the times the problem is that Power Save Mode is enabled, to disable go to Current inspection profile (lower right corner in Android Studio).@Nanda R.M stikom

Comment: Android Studio Chipmunk breaks with `compileSdk 33`, but updating to Dolphin or above fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you will not get suggestions until your project is rightly indexed. So before the indexing is complete, you will see this problem. Once the indexing of files is complete, you should be able to see the suggestions.

However, if the indexing is complete and you still do not get the suggestion, I would like to recommend to install the latest version of Android Studio again and do not import any settings from your previous version.

You can also try looking for if the Power Saving Mode and invalidating the cache. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/3145960) addresses the same issue I think where you might have a look as well.

Comment: The second image was my entire project, as u can see there is no indexing process there. And yes now im trying to update my AS and nothing change. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I see, can you please try the options mentioned in the link that I have posted?

Comment: Yes i already try that before asking. 
my power saving mode is not enable from beginning. and i try to enable and disable again still nothing happen T-T.

Comment: Absolutely, nothing wrong than suggestion :D.
i'm not getting problem like this before and i'm not changing anything to the project. should i restart my PC ?

Comment: LOL. That's weird. You might try that as well I think. :P

Comment: Thanks for help, and sorry i'm not active for a few days maybe :D. 
I fix it little different, after doing so much experiments, the last thing i do is going to delete configuration setting for Android Studio on "C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudio<x.xx>" then all fixed.
But i ll chose ur answer as accepted answer. Sorry my english bad ;v

Answer (score 12):

Have the same issue, **delete caches, invalidate caches or disable power mode** is **not work** for me

I change compileSdk from 33 to 30

and it's work

I use Android studio chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Maybe new feature still not work properly or something. If anyone can explain this will be very helpfull

Comment: For me, it worked after downgrading the SDK version from 33 to 32.

Comment: For me it works when downgraded compilesdk from 33 to 32

Comment: Downgrading from 33 to 32 is not the ultimate solution. It can be a temporarily solve your problem.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried different things(deleting **.idea** folder and **.iml** files from the project, invalidate cache and restart the Android Studio) nothing worked.

Finally I close the Android Studio and navigate to android studio installation directory(i.e C:\Users\Your Username\.AndroidStudio3.3\system) delete the **Cache** folder, run the android studio and it's works for me.

Comment: You saved my time bro. Really appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Please change the compileSdkVersion to 32. It worked for me.

Comment: This Could be marked as a temporary solution. But for now its worked.

Answer (score 4):

**First solution**

Deleting the `.idea` folder and all `.iml` files from the project, restarting Android Studio and rebuilding a gradle did the trick. Autocomplete in XML support library is working again.

**Second Solution**

Just navigate to your android studio installation directory: `your_drive_path:/.AndroidStudio3.4/system`

Inside system folder: **DELETE CACHE FOLDER**

Answer (score 4):

1- close the android studio entirely.

2- Open `File explorer` and go to:
   `C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio3.5\system`.

3- Now delete the `Caches folder`.

4- Run the android studio.

5- After indexing it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Change the compile sdk version to

```
compileSdk 32
```

and also for kotlin

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I change compileSdk from 33 to 32 then its work for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2.

In my case, i tried all the invalidate caches and restart, and other approaches too. But overall the suggestions did not show up. It turns out On of the **Android studio plugins was outdated** and is not compatible with the AS version. **I removed all the unnecessary plugins.** Invalidated caches and restarted, then suggestions appeared.

Answer (score 0):

First Close Android Studio.
Navigate to the Installation Directory.
i.e.
**.AndroidStudio3.3\system**
Delete **Cache** Folder .
Start Android Studio.
It is supposed to Work.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio closed go to the Path **C/Users/you_user/AndroidStudio3.6\system** and delete the content of **caches**

Answer (score 0):

Go to path/.C:\Users\Hp.AndroidStudio4.0\system/ delete caches folder

and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate caches... did not work for me

Clean Project, and Rebuild Project... did not work for me

But changing module level gradle's

> compileSdk to 31, and targetSdk to 31

did work for me!

I guess some issues with SDK version 33

Answer (score 0):

I tried all, Invalidate Cache, Restart, Clean, and rebuild the project.
Downgrading from SDK 33 to 30 also I did after searching.
Nothing worked.

In the end, I updated my Android Studio from Chipmunk to Dolphin.
Everything is sorted now.

So the final conclusion that worked for me is:
**Update the Android Studio**

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have in app build.gradle -> implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

Me help it

Answer (score 0):

in my case it has been solved by decreasing compileSdk and targetSdk to version 31 and then Ive changed some of dependencies versions
for example :

implementation `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0`
implementation `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2`
implementation `com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1`
implementation `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4`
testImplementation `junit:junit:4.13.2`
androidTestImplementation `androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3`
androidTestImplementation `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0`

notice that my
android gradle plugin version :7.2.1
Gradle Version :7.3.3

Answer (score -1):

100 % working solution

I am a starter in android development and I started off with eclipse.. But it started giving lot of problems. So I switched to android studio. Got it set up successfully and for couple of weeks it was ok. Now, for some reason, the auto complete feature is not working. It is not giving any choices while typing, so I tried ctrl–enter. It says no suggestions. I browsed through similar queries and tried the following.

Disabling Power Save in File menu.
Checking basic complete and smart type completion in IDE settings (editor)
Invalidate caches and restart.
But non of these seems to work.

**These following steps are working for me:**

Close android studio
Go to path/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/ delete caches folder
Start Android Studio
,

**I had the same issue and solved it.**
Go File> Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

If none of work :

**Try with CTRL + space and you will 100% get the drop down** .