# autosuggestion not working in android studio

Tags: android-studio

when I click on ctrl+space but not get auto-suggestion like if I type t than not get drop down box (textColor,textSize) data type of suggestion so what should I do
    I am try

> 1-: clear invalidate catches and restart
>       2-:restart PC
>       3-:delete all iml file

when I click ctrl+space I got only three suggestion like(android: than style than tools) but if I click on android and return click ctrl_space than I got the red message no suggestion what should I do.
please check attachment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW8Q5.png)

Comment: possible https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/9823185. check it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Comment: not working restart and catch here