# dart analyzer tool window is not showing in android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

dart analyser tool window not showing after updating plugins and suggestions also not showing. even everything is showing well

```
    • Flutter version 1.10.16-pre.67 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision e3742b6e41 (15 hours ago), 2019-11-06 23:13:17 -0500
    • Engine revision c448d39d53
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\dheer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

by this image i want to show dart analyzer tool window is not showing
[image: by this image i want to show dart analyzer tool window is not showing]

Comment: You mean `Dart Analysis`?

Comment: yes, dart analysis

Comment: error solved by trying this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388983/11955278

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on the icon on the bottom left corner, and choose 'Dart Analysis'.

[image]