# Android Studio does not support code completion for CardView from AndroidX, how to fix this?

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx

I've added the Cardview to `build.gradle` under `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Gradle did not complain. When I try to use it in `activity_main.xml`, it seems to work, but for some reason, Android Studio does not offer syntax completion a CardView block. See the image below.

My Android Studio version is 3.5.3.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to Android.

[image]

Comment: possible this topic help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Comment: @javaddroid, you were absolutely right, thank you so much! would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept and close it?

Comment: of course. hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an android studio fault that might be accurate some times. 
you can use `Invalidate cache and restart` from  `file menu`.

if problem not solve look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)