# Auto complete (suggestions) not work in android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

android studio don't suggestions in XML ( suggestions in XML not work but in java work)

I see [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

and do:
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

but not fix
and power save is disabled

[image: don't work]

- 

but still not work,
how can fix this?

Comment: Clean rebuild and then invalidate and restart