# Autocompete not working in Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So, it is my day 4 into android dev. Built a Bmi calculator app today. After which I opened a new project(following my udemy tutorials). Following that, no autocomplete function works. Even in my old projects, it has stopped working.
Someone suggested me to disable power saving mode, but it always off. Still, no respite and I am really frustrated. [Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic1Bm.png)
Normally, it would suggest height and width+the src code. Which isn't happening now.
Please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and or rebuild the project? In the top bar go to Build -> Clean Project and after that try Build -> Rebuild Project. If that doesn't work you can try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... In the dialog that pops up choose Invalidate And Restart. One of these options usually work for me. Good Luck!