# Cannot resolve class of basic widget in xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Happen on Android Studio Preview - Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Beta 4.

[image]

I've tried literally everything from multiple questions on SO; Clean Build, Invalidate Caches and Restart, remove root project's `.gradle` and `.idea`, remove caches folder in `.gradle`, even remove and download Android Studio again, you name it.

It's been almost a day and still can't figure it out, please help, this is killing my motivation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve this problem myself.

The steps are to **remove the current project --> clone the project again from git --> Re-import project and rebuild.**

Android Studio is funny sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem with an old project written totally in Java.
Adding the following dependency in the project gradle file solved the problem.

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
```

Comment: Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2, the same problem. Adding this dependency helped me, thanks.

Comment: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 - same problem, adding this dependency solved it. Thanks kind stranger!

Comment: It worked on Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1, , when updated kotlin gradle plugin version from 1.7.10 to 1.8.0 (suggested by IDE).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that Android studio **can't recognize** the xml elements

⛔ Problem

```
Cannot resolve class layout
Element layout must be declared
```

✅ Solution

```
Is the clear the cache of Android Studio
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for imageView

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView />
```

instead of

```
<ImageView />
```

and for textView use this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView />
```

instead of

```
<TextView />
```

Comment: Yes I know, Ibrahim. But I want to find a way to fix the root cause of my problem, not a work-around to avoid it.

Comment: I found a solution yesterday, try to add EmptyActivity to the project it will download missing packages containing these. @Son Phan

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting `~/.gradle` and invalidating caches did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

For me updating the kotlin version resolved that.

Comment: Kotlin version has nothing to do with your views.