# (Solved and Stuck): Android Studio Bug for Git for Mac OS this time, in windows it is fine

Tags: git, macos, android-studio, plugins

To Android Studio,

[image: The Android Studio (My Latest Version)].

Every time I start Android Studio (Bumble Patch 2 Now), I see in the Git setting section that either the Git folder is not recognized as a dedicated folder for Git, OR that I have to hit the test button to get its version. More details follow towards the bottom of the question posted here.

[This time [Bumblebee patch 1 and one version before] Every time Android Studio is started, coming to this part of the setup for Git version control, shows that it is not installed and needs to be downloaded. A red line for the required Git version needed does not go away (see highlighted in red: Supported for Git 2.9), which obviously should go after the version of installed Git is known already.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI9MY.png)

[image: needs to download everytime]

[OR It sometimes just needs for the ***test*** button to be clicked, and the version of Git that was not found before gets updated below button. Support for Git version 2.9 (should be read as Git version 2.09 and not 2.90? which is less than 2.17, but might be greater if seen otherwise, following the decimal rules), which I have installed, but is always required (and again it does not go away)? Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYkbI.png)

[image: only the test button is needed to be clicked, but always on start.]
Details:- [The Git fails to get configured by the user/Android Studio in Mac HighSierra.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221575659)

[NOTE: Previous Android Studio Error: Previously the error was for data binding, where new view ids were not recognized, I don't have the solution yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69208045/787399)

**Update :-** Trying to see whether the solution in the following link works or not. [The solution I found, to be tried](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-git#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20update,Git%20overwrites%20the%20current%20installation.)

I checked the version of the current Git installed :-

```
$ git --version
git version 2.35.1
```

Used the update command :-

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade git
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Warning: git 2.35.1 already installed
```

**Results :-**

Then I followed :- [Official Site](https://git-scm.com/download/mac) which provides the latest update using an installation file. [Note :- it said the latest version that will be installed from it is version 2.33.0 which is less than my current version :- 2.35.1]

The brighter side is that It will give the functionality till it knows that the current version is 2.17

Comment: I may have encountered the same issue a few times in the last couple of weeks.  By clearing caches several times, rebooting, clicking that test button you mentioned, etc., I've been able to make it find git again.  But I don't know which steps matter or in which order.  Plus the issue keeps coming back.

Comment: I also posted the issue in the Android Studio Forum. Maybe they will release a patch. In windows now it is working fine.

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky What I think now is that the support for GIT on my mac OS High Sierra 10.13, will not go beyond version 2.17, but in Windows 10, there might be no such conflict of version, so it is running smoothly there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong. My GIT version is 2.35.1, but Android Studio on my mac OS v 10.13, does not show it beyond 2.17.

What I think now is that the support for GIT on my mac OS High Sierra 10.13, will not go beyond version 2.17. But in Windows 10, there might be no such conflict of version, so it is running smoothly there. Maybe the updated version is installed that is above the minimum version required there!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeMTW.png) is the current GIT version showing in Android Studio installed in Windows 10 OS. This will be enough to prove that I have to purchase another latest expensive macOS Desktop or Laptop.

[image: This is what is shown in Windows OS]

But I can prevent a need for that purchase, I always use GIT from the command line or use GitHub Desktop for macOS.