# Android Studio broke down Error:error: package xxx does not exist, error: cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Android Studio broke down after merge in git
this is the correct path but Android studio thinks otherwise

I tried everything, any advice ? the path is valid, on another computer the same repository working

ofc i made hard reset git,checkout, i tryed Invalidate caches

[image]

also sometimes have same like this:
[Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Comment: Try clean and build the project again

Comment: Clone the project again and build the project if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the project again and build the project if possible