# Error:(66, 30) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'

Tags: android

In every instance in all of my classes where I reference `R.id.something`, the R is in red and it says "cannot resolve symbol R".
And when I run 'app', it shows all the 'textColor' in styles.xml getting an error.

Comment: Check which R file is imported!

Comment: Debug in your app...

Comment: when i click 'debug app' i will get: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'.and debug stopped

Comment: @Alexander Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

**@Alexander** : `Main reason is R.java not generating` .

Open the **Android SDK Manager and Update with latest**:

1. Android SDK Tools
2. Android SDK Build Tools

Then ***Clean with Re-Build and Restart*** Your Project

> ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

And

> [Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Try this way ,I hope it will helps you .

Comment: I update SDK and restart project but the error still exists.I delete xml files which i create lately,but it's doesn't work

Comment: @Alexander Update support repository .

Comment: @Alexander This is a very common problem .Using Android studio or eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem of appcompat.. untill your res folder contains error. R.java will not be generated.