# Error cannot resolve symbol 'R' of R.id.toolbar, in android studio

Tags: android

I have pasted following code in `style.xml`, replacing previous default code in `style.xml`, and I am getting following Error in `MainActivity.Java':

> Error cannot resolve symbol 'R'  of R.id.toolbar

I am new android developer, Please support!

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Primary theme color of the app (sets background color of app bar) -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item>
    <!-- Background color of buttons in the app -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: post your activity_main.xml, and you MainActivity.jave

Comment: the R class can't compiled if there are any error in xml files ,, make sure that your xml style code is has no error

Comment: Just clean and rebuild your project

Comment: how can i make sure the my XML file has no error if no Error shows up in XML file in Android Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

If cleaning and rebuilding doesn't work, try `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're user of Android Studio. Try to:
Build -> Clean Project
Build -> Rebuild project

See this: [Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio first check your build.gradle file to make sure that you have compiled appcompat support library in your project. if not add this in order to add the library to your project

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

and after that clean and build project.

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1  already present in build.gradle in dependencies

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.R;
```

import this in your MainActivity.
Then GOTO 
Build---> Clean Project

Comment: After  import android.R;  and then cleaning the project, previous error of 'R' seems resolved but now same Error (can't resolve the symbol) is appearing on many other  characters like in ' R.Layout.activitymain' : it is appearing for 'activitymain'

Comment: may the name of your xml layout is diffrent as mentioned in MainActivity.Java check it out
Try it as activity_main

Comment: adding `android.R` can never be a solution.. It refers to the default resources provided by Android.. Not the layout and styles we have added explicitly..!!