# "can not resolve symbol R" when creating multiple variants of App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I am trying to create multiple product Flavors of my Application to do that, I have updated my **app/build.gradle** file with the product flavors like this...

```
...
productFlavors{
        free{
            applicationId "com.demoname.free"
        }
        paid{
            applicationId "com.demoname.paid"
        }
    }
...
```

And then I have just added new String Resources files to each flavor which went smoothly.

But when I tried to add activities in each flavor I am getting error saying Cannot resolve symbol R in my new product flavor's activity java code.

I tried rebuilding application and tried cleaning application too.

I have checked manifest file of the variants and the package names are correct in those files.

Even the activity names are not conflicting between these variants.

what am I missing?

I have tried options on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but) link

Comment: Removed the `r` tag, which is referred to the statistical programming language.

Comment: I think you completely changed the package name, therefore none of your resource variables will be resolvable. Are you sure that's how you implement product flavors?