# R.layout is'nt recogized by the studio

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

suddenly `R`isn't recognized, probably something I have done.

Can someone explain to me what does it mean the `R.layout`...? 
And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart`

Comment: Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but

Comment: If `R` isn't recreated after a clean build there is maybe an error in one of the resource files.

Comment: did you renamed ur package or did you renamed somthing in resource folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the problem because of some changes in layout..

Build-> Clean Project and then you will get build fail because of some error, then solve that error you will get appropriate result.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime if your xml file have some error, the studio will not auto generate the R.java

Answer (score 1):

Restart the android studio. If doesn't work then it might be problem with theme.

Answer (score 1):

First Rebuild your Gradle by doing this `Build -> Rebuild Projects` if that doesn't work. In your Project bar(left side of your screen), goto **Gradle Scripts** and double click on **build.gradle** file, inside that file check your dependencies if your have something similar to this `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` there, if you don't have it just copy and paste this there and then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this may help,

Go to your manifest file, `change the package name, and make a Project Clean.`