# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' in a module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm finally migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio and can't even connect a little module.

Here's the only file in resources - as you can see by a screenshot, there is no error there

[image]

But in the class where it is needed 'R' is not resolved. So I'm confused - there is not too much to look into

[image]

There are problems in App's module as I didn't hook all the libraries yet, but no obvious problem in 'dragsortlib' module.
I cleaned, rebuilt project but this didn't help.

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobeta.android.dslv"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="0.6.1">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7"
        android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Try File>Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Comment: Can u check is there any errors in manifest?

Comment: Dont forget to import the R.

Comment: do you have R class imported?

Comment: @VladMatvienko alt+Enter doesn't give me this option to import it

Comment: Why on earth do I get Downvotes ????

Comment: Can u post screenshot of your manifest and build.gradle?

Comment: You can try to build your project without using that resources in your JAVA files firstly. I suspect some mistakes in XML files, that don't show up before build.

Comment: @Raghavendra updated, added them

Comment: You are not compiling the project you added. You have  to add it in dependencies  like this .

`compile project(':dragsortlib').`

Answer (score 2):

Click on Build -> Rebuild Project and then click Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

You may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Answer (score 1):

1. First check the import of R file
2. Delete build folder under app manually and Build project again.
3. Check your xml files. R.java is not generated if you have errors in your xml file.
4. Lastly update your build tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make clear that this **Error** occurs while there is any issue in your **res** folder and it is not allowing to auto generate resource id in **R.Java** file. So look it carefully in your resource folder and manifest what causes this error.

It would be a little mistake causing this error, Once you find that mistake you can easily resolve this error, But most of the case you need to **Clean Project** or **Invalidate Cache and Restart** will work after resolving issue.

Hope this will work.