# Android Studio Cant resolve symbol 'R' first Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started my first time android studio. Tried to run hello world but got an error. "Cant resolve symbol 'R' " tips from the internet like clear and rebuild didn´t work! 
I haven´t changed anything after creating the project. I also reinstalled android studio multiple times now but the problem is still there.
Until now i have no clue about android studio but experience with java.

Nothing is changed and i allways get the red R. i would be so thankfull if you can help me out of this.

Edit: the duplicate is very similar but i´ve looked up my files now, but i
found no error. I don´t use Eclipse btw.

If i add an:`import android.R;` the problem seems to be solved but activity_main gets red then. And i prefer a "normal" solution. There must be a difference why other people can run hello world without problems.
While checking the log i found something.`C:\Users\J?rgen\.......` file not found.
this occures multiple times all files are in the right direction. but the non ascii char could cause the problem.

I had a similar problem before, is it possible to move the automatically created files to something like `C:\xyz....`

Comment: look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but

Comment: There is likely a problem in one of your resource files. Carefully read the error messages.

Comment: This sounds like you have an error somewhere in a resource or XML file. Please check the log for build errors, fix them and then try a build again

Comment: show your logs please

Answer (score 0):

Try Invalidating Caches. You will get this option in Android Studio Files -> Invalidate Cache/Restart.