# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' error in app level gradle.build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, appcompatactivity

I working on a project and i add some dependencies to that project. But i got some errors in app level **gradle.build** file 
I am using Android Studio 3.1 new version. All settings are default i'm not change anything. All settings are came with new downloaded version with 3.1

Give me a error in this line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'`

My problem is cannot run project in Android Studio emulator

This is my app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.blogapp.anu.blogapp"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Seems i'm using same version for all. And i already read some questions and apply them, but not work for me.

this is my project level

```
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath  'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

This is my Android SDK Platforms which i using right now
[image: Android SDK Platforms Screenshot]

> And in every instance in all of my classes where I reference
>   `R.id.something`, the R is in red and it says "`cannot resolve symbol R`".

Anyone know what wrong with my codes?

Comment: Try to clean your project from build option in the android studio.

Comment: @RishabhRawat i did it but same the result. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Comment: check the library file you using might be they use different build tools version because of that also problem will happen.

Comment: post your log here

Comment: What is the error exactly?. You are not able to run the project?. Or it's a warning saying a higher version is available .

Comment: My problem is cannot run project in Android Studio emulator

Comment: Post your complete app level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani i already added it in my question

Comment: The one having `(Project: project name)` on the right of the gradle file.

Comment: ah that is project level gradle file. i also add fully code to my question can you please check it out

Comment: Oh thank you. Sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in app level gradle

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' 



 implementation com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' implementation 
    'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
```

add this in project level gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'**

Comment: this is look like comment see the link how to paste good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

if your doing some Major changes you need to Restart your **Android Studios** `File->Invalidate caches/Restart`

---

**Solution 2:**
If you are using external libs:

Goto `File -> Settings -> Compiler` now check use **external build** clean and rebuild..

then rebuild project

---

**Solution 3:**

change into `buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"`

Add `dependencies`

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Try all the 3 solutions but not worked sir, may be problem is my SDK Platforms? i'm using Oreo and Nougat

Comment: No issues bro..i think you didnot download SDK repositories..Please download it..check it

Comment: Those are i'm using currently. https://imgur.com/a/c87jd  Any new thing need to added bro?

Comment: still got error in that line bro implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal ok,,,tell me one thing still you getting  **R.id.something, the R is in red and it says "cannot resolve symbol R".** this error

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try replacing the 2 lines

```
 compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

with

```
 implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

Also, for R not being importing to your packages import statemt, yo can navigate to R keyword in your code and press `Alt + Enter` and then select `import class` from the menu.

Comment: Sir replace not worked, and Alt + Enter show me Create Test option

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal Try navigating where you have occurence of "R" in your code and then enter `Alt+Enter`.
Also you can try importing the statement yourself as `import com.blogapp.anu.blogapp.R;`

Answer (score -1):

it is because of your firebase implementation issue...

add this ...

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: No sir, it not worked. anyway can you explain more why you called "
it is because of your firebase implementation issue "

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'   modify all this implementation

Comment: can you show me project level gradle.build  ...add this         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' version

Comment: buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'  change this to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168021/discussion-between-sahan-pasindu-nirmal-and-user8311225).