# (R.layout.activity_main)? R is in red color

Tags: android

My error in Android Studio is that it give red R (R.layout.activity_main) in MainActivity.java file. I trid my best to solve error by cleaning and rebilding the projects but can't.

([Android Studio marks R in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol R", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but/32382873))

My Mainactivity.java code is here:

```
package com.example.zeeshan.myapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Timer timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
timer =new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
}, 5000);
}
}
```

Following is my AndroidManfifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zeeshan.myapplication">
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I was expecting that my app launch succesfuuly but it does not .. plz help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your android studio, if it doesn't fix your problem.
Look at your imports you might have called the same import twice if so remove one of the imports.