# Why does Android Studio Java pages has errors on R.id?

Tags: java, android-studio

I just started a college project with android studio, and I faced so many errors recently it was ok before!

all the `activities.java` have errors but `XMLs` is fine
I had one error and I send it to someone and he said he fixed it.
that error is gone now but so many other errors appeared.

All the Javas have these same errors (R.id has red underline):

```
btnMakeCall = findViewById(R.id.support_call_btn);
btnSendEmail = findViewById(R.id.support_send_email_btn);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

**MainActivity** has these errors also (all are red underlined):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

TextSliderView textSliderView;
RelativeLayout relativeLayoutPardakhtGhabz;
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but/32382873

Comment: thank you guess i found the solution there