# BuildConfig is not working in Android studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

I was trying to get current **version name** of my android studio project. after updating my Studio to **3.6.1** i am facing difficulty in importing **BuildConfig**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio marks things in red with error message "cannot resolve symbol ...", but build succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed this as well.

It was after a 'Clean Project' that AS forgot the `import com.my_project.BuildConfig;` statement.

Restoring the import statement manually wherever it was complaining about BuildConfig and then doing a 'Rebuild Project' seemed to work, at least until the next time.

Tip: don't accept the offered suggestion to import the class from ...compat.v4... you want the app level definition.

***Update April 4th:*** The newly released AS 3.6.2 doesn't seem to suffer from this problem.