# R.java does not regenerate in any way

Tags: android, eclipse, project, r.java-file

I have a big project into eclipse.

After I upgraded from SDK manager, R.java gave problems and I deleted it.
Now it remains only the folder "gen" empty.

I tried, without success, these things:

-**clean project** with and without "Build automatically", without any error (reported by eclipse) in the file inside the folder res

-**ctrl-shift-o**

-remove **android.import.R**

-**F5**

space and then remove the add-in **manifest**

-check the **PACKAGE** of the project

-**restart** eclipse

-**restart** the pc

-exclude the project from eclipse and then **import** it again

- .. and anything I read in these 2 DAYS

What can I do??

Comment: also check all the file name from drawable and layouts are in smaller case.try it in new work space..

Comment: already done .. maybe the problem and had it fixed ZouZou Beko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened the same thing to me yesterday. I re-open the SDK Manager and suprisely some stuff in the tools folder wer'ent upgraded. Launch the SDK manager and check if you got the last revisions of this stuff. Then restart Eclipse and rebuild your project.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!:) Android SDK tools has not been updated, who knows why!?

Comment: I thank you very much resolved, the problem was that the SDK tools had not been properly updated, thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, did you update the SDK the last 2 days?  (API 17)? There is probably a problem with that, try updating it again, it will probably work again.

If not you can try **Project** > **Clean**. Also the drawable and layouts mustn't contain any errors or capitals...

Comment: I thank you very much resolved, the problem was that the SDK tools had not been properly updated, thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Might be the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570).

> After updating to SDK Tools to rev. 22 for the first time, you may
>   need to relaunch Android SDK Manager again and install a new item:
>   **Android SDK Build-tools**. [image]
>
> After installing this, clean your projects and rebuild.