# R.java is getting deleted while creating a new activity

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse Juno IDE for my android development. I recently installed the latest ADT  22.0.0 plugin. After that I am facing an issue.

Whenever I create a new application, R.java file is automatically deleted. 
For existing projects which have had no issues, R.java file is getting deleted when Build the project or clean it.

I have tried my best to sort out this issue, and it still exists.
Has anybody faced or facing similar issue??
Is there a way this can be resolved ?? Any suggestions out there...

I am giving minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="17"

Please help at the earliest possible.

Comment: It's one of the most common problems in ADT 22. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247).

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623439/r-java-does-not-regenerate-in-any-way/16623470#16623470

Comment: Thanks to all.. The issue is now resolved...

I just updated the SDK and bingo... the issue is gone

Answer (score 0):

is it for one project or all the project? I hope its happening for the single new project you are trying to create.

Usually this error occurs when you have errors in your xml files. Please go through your `xml` files to see if there are any errors. Once you fix any errors in the xml files check your source files and remove any reference to the `R` file. Remove any import that references the R file.

Now re-build your project. It should work now I suppose.

### Update

Ok it's an issue with the new SDK follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570) to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Mayu... Thanks for your reply...

Initially I thought of errors in XML file, but could not find any.

When I tried to create a new application with Blank Activity through the wizard, the R.java file is deleted immediately after the application is created. I am confused here... How a newly created activity can have errors in XML...?

Comment: @Justin yeah if its a new project then you can't have errors in it.did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570)