# R.java missing in Android

Tags: android, r.java-file

Okay so I'm using Juno and my gen folder does not have R.java. I tried the following steps:

Clean the project(10 times).
Fix Project Properties.
Check for errors in my xml files.
Checked Android 4.2.2 in Porperties->Android.

I know there has been a lot of discussion on this but none of them work for me.
Is there anything else I can try to generate my R.java?
Please help.

Comment: I know you said you checked your xml for errors but did you make sure to check `manifest.xml` also? I ask because people seem to miss that one quite often

Comment: Did you recently update your ADT ?

Comment: If `R.java` is not being generated, there will definitely be a problem reported somewhere: Eclipse Console, Eclipse Problems tab, etc.

Comment: Yes I did update my ADT today!

Comment: @Nemin Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623439/r-java-does-not-regenerate-in-any-way/16623470#16623470

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you updated your ADT, did you try to change the API level for your emulator? My problem was similar, and I was trying to use level 8 and the libraries I was using required level 11 so went one by one until I figured out which one to use.

Comment: No there was no problem with my API level. The SDK Tool folder did not install the new updates. So that's why my R.java was not getting generated!