# Phone not connecting to eclipse since update to ADB 22

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, adb, galaxy

My Samsung Galaxy S2 is not connecting to eclipse after I updated the ADT to version 22.
I reinstalled all the drivers for the phone, restarted both computer and phone multiple times but nothing seems to work. I've also tried to list the devices from the adb command promt but even those list didn;t show anything. I really need a solution because this is very frustrating.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Re-open your adt and check if you have downloaded all the stuff. Check if the android SDK build-tools is downloaded (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623439/r-java-does-not-regenerate-in-any-way/16623470#16623470)

Comment: Everything is downloaded and up to date, R file is being generated, thats not the problem.. I can build the project and launch it on an AVD but not on my phone..

Comment: Did you enable debugging on your phone ?

Comment: Yes, USB debuggins is enabled, everything worked before the update to 22, maybe i can try the new android Studio ?

In device manager my phone is listed as SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface so the drivers are OK and my phone is sending the right signal..

Comment: Did you update the android plug-ins in eclipse ?

Comment: I think I did, because I just downloaded the new package from [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and When i hit Help -> Check for updates, eclipse says there are no updates found