# ADT 22 with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, adt

I recently updated my [adt](/questions/tagged/adt) and when i import the [actionbarsherlock](/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock) the project is full of errors. Before the update everything was working fine. How can i fix this?

Comment: Check this answer. It helped me solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update

Comment: thanks but this was the first think i checked!

Comment: didn't it help you? Try to restart Eclipse or Computer and rebuild the project.

Comment: no the problem hasn't been solved. In the beginning in all of my projects i had errors and after i made the solution you suggest to me everything solved except the actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 2):

Right click to ActionBarSherlock project. Go to menu Properties and then "Order and export" and check 'Android Private Libraries' checkbox. Click 'Apply'. Rebuild ActionBarSherlock. 
Make same with your project. Rebuild your project.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update). Also, try this: right-click your project->Properties->Java Build Path->check the "android private libraries".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did what you told me but it still doesn't work.

Comment: yes and before post my question i searched about it and i installed the sdk-build tools. Now i download the adt bundle and i will install from the beginning!

Comment: You can check whether the library imports are correct. Right-click project-> properties-> Android-> scroll to bottom, check the library reference is correct. Or right-click project->Java Build Path-> libraries, check the external jars have no error.

Comment: i checked this because i delete the actionbarsherlock and i import it again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

After you update everything and you restart/refresh it will show another option "Android SDK-Build Tool" Install this and it will fix the problem.

You can find more on this here.Check this answer. It helped me solve this problem. [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update)

Update: Restart your Eclipse after you install everything and rebuild all the projects that have problems. It should fix everything. I am on Mac. Maybe if you are on Windows then you have to restart computer.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the actionbarsherlock and i changed the project build target to 4.2.2 and after that i cleaned the project!