# cannot resolve R into variable after Android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated my android studio and now all my resources are errors!

- I have debugged and debugged but no avail.
- All my xmls files are okay,
- all strings start with lower case.
- I have also restarted the program

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug in the newest version of android studio 0.1.6. Google has suggested a temporary workaround until they can track down the problem and fix in next release. turn off external builds in preferences > compiler.

Comment: Theres no such option in Preferences. I updated AS to version 0.3.7 :(

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have updated the `Android SDK Tools` to version 22, but you might not have updated the `Android SDK Build-Tools` to the latest version. Update it from the sdk manager and restart. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16608570/1306419) answer on similar question: [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?lq=1) . Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the build button in android studio? .... use it and click rebuild project, see what happens.

Comment: rebuilding the project will work, but you have to rebuild the project every time you make a change with this current bug. see my answer for google's suggested workaround.

Comment: I updated my studio today, i don't seem to see this bug but alright

Comment: many people are. maybe it is not affecting everyone: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Been on the forums on your link and rebuild has surprisingly helped many people, including me. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

"Settings"/"Preferences" -> "Compiler"
Check "Use external build" if you are using gradle and uncheck "Use external build" if you are NOT using gradle.

Sources:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56531

Comment: No such option in AS 0.3.1 :(

Answer (score 1):

That error went away for me when I simply Built the project (Ctrl+F9).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, all you have to do is press, "Build > Rebuild Project" before each Run or debug. I hope this error is fixed asap.

Answer (score 0):

Updated "Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager" updated tools and SDK to latest version.

Also updated android:targetSdkVersion="18" to latest in AndroidManifest.xml and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio `can not resolve R error` is occured due to
build.gradle file the minmum sdk and `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` sdk platform should be installed and if updates avilable update it first.
Another thing `buildToolsVersion` and `android.support:appcompat` should be clear so no ambiguity found. You can set these manually from build.gradle or from `File -> Project Structure -> app` and `Flavors`.
[image]
Some other causes of R can not be resolve can be due to error in `.xml`  file. Most time I solve my issue with these methods.