# Android Studio issue with R file

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using Android studio now for a long time and it was fine. Recently, not sure what happened, but when I click on debug and have it perform `make` it complains about the R file and it seems like it doesn't generate it.

The only way it works is if I click on `Build > Rebuild Project`...problem is that it takes a long time for that to go through.

Is there anything I am missing? I updated the Android SDK tools, etc. as per some of the other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a known issue in the newest version of android studio. Google has suggested a temporary workaround until they can track down the problem and fix in next release. Turn off external builds in `preferences > compiler`. It might help.

Source: [cannot resolve R into variable after Android studio update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255918/cannot-resolve-r-into-variable-after-android-studio-update/17255957#17255957) and  [R.java not updated after update to 0.1.6](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for android studio Users :

**Goto** : Menu tab - > Build - > Rebuild Project

after rebuild Project.R.Java file will be solve automatically ..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but it looks like a new update came out today. It seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import android.R, for every class you need R (of the package)
and then compile, it makes different error from before.

And remove all ('import android.R') , and rebuild it.

This trick is not for solving problem in proper way,
but makes the tool refresh.

Answer (score -1):

And remove all "import android.R" , and rebuild it and import them again its working for me