# R Cannot be Resolved to a Variable - on All my Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

So , this Morning ,

- i launched `Eclipse` ,
- i do somes Modification on a String , on `Res/Value/String.xml` ,
- i modified Juste One String , then i saved , i get `"R Cannot be
  Resolved to a Variable" Error` ,
- Then i undo my Modification on this String ,
- i tried to Clean my Project , i have Checked all Ressource Name/Files
  , i Checked for Update on Eclipse(Notice that i have Updated Adb/Eclipse/SDK Just
  somes Days ago ...) ,
- & Now , `"R Cannot be Resolved to a Variable"` Error **Affect All my
  Projects** into Workspace ,

I had Already this Error before but i fixed it , but Now im Lost ,

Anyone Know something about that Error ?

Comment: Make sure you also have "Android SDK-Build Tools" installed from the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Yes i have , i just Checked now ...

Comment: With reference to @KenWolf comment, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16608570/2345913)

Comment: Better to create one new project and see you still get this error

Comment: i have also tried in Command Line ''eclipse.exe -clean'' with No Luck

Comment: @Brijesh Thakur , i have Deleted the Project from WorkSpace Then Imported again with No Luck too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you updated updated Eclipse.. so try this..

- Start Android SDK Manager
- Look for any more updates available..
- Install updates and restart Eclipse
- Also go to Help->Check for Updates and install updates.

repeat the last two step mentioned above till you get no updates available.

Restart Eclipse Again and the check..

Comment: Yes i have Updated Everything & no there is No Update avaible anymore

Comment: Are you sure your own R.java file is generated and there is no error in your xml files...??

Comment: No , sorry i have not Mentionned , i have Lost(i have No) R.java File anymore gen & bin Folder are empty & i have a assets/fonts/ Folder & a File "A.ttf" inside but this assets Folder look like Empty in Eclipse IDE

Comment: Ok, create a new ANdroid project, a simple Hello world project, check the issue still remains, if not, then, solution is simple create a new project and add all related files. (Note donot import project but add files)

Comment: Ok , i have Created a New Project "Hello World" & i get the same "R Cannot be Resolved to a Variable" Error , Please notice that i have Unchecked "Android" on Properties>Java Build Path just before to try to Resolve this Issue

Comment: Why did you do that for,Go Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and export --> Tick Android Version Checkbox,, this could be one of solution... restart eclipse then...

Comment: Thats Crazy Fcking Error !!

Comment: right click /gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore. This will not solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.. You get to know if there where actually error in layout, or drawable etc..

Comment: Thanks for your Help , but i get a Message "No deleted Ressources in local history for the Selected Container"

Comment: Oh boy!! Hmm, I hope you must have maintained backup of your project at some point of time, try copy that R.java file inside your project, then save-- refresh project-- clean and build your project..

Comment: Yes , but there were Many Many Changes since my Last Backup

Comment: Its ok, just copy it, I am expecting eclipse to overwite it once you clean and build...Try it for once..

Comment: Ok , ill try ... so i am going to get the R File from my Last Backup & put it into my Project , but Why All My Projects are Affected with this Error , is there Something Wrong with Eclipse/SDK ?

Comment: Does no Work , Gen Folder still appear as Empty in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the import statements.

Does it say `import android.R`? Delete that line and import `R` again, making sure it's the one from your project's package, not Android's.

Comment: Already checked , & no android.R & No Visible Error on my Xml Files

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps in your Eclipse

1. Right click on your Project name and select Properties.
2. Click on Android on make sure the Target name under the Project Build Target is checked. If not, enable the checkbox.
3. Click on Apply
4. Right click on your Project again and select build bath and then Configure Build Path
5. Under the Order and Export make sure the Android Library and any other referencing Libraries and selected.
6. Click on OK
7. Now Clean and build your project again and it should resolve the issue

Thanks
Ameya

Comment: 2. Android 4.0 was already Checked
5. Android 4.0 was Unchecked , i Checked it Then Cleanned my Project , but this does Not Resolve my Issue :( , & i say Again , All my Projects are Affected with the Same Error ...

Comment: Did you perform steps 4-7? you need to perform steps 4-7 as well, try it!

Comment: Yes , i did All Steps you Mentionned

Comment: OK, hover your mouse over the Android.R variable and click on Fix project setup, this will provide you with an option to select the SDK, select it and your error should go away

Comment: mouse over Android.R Variable ? What is that , i have already tried Android Tools>Fix Project Properties , Maybe Unistall Eclipse/SDK and Reinstall All ?

Comment: Clicking on Fix Project Properties from Android tools doesn't work at times. It didn't work for me when I was trying to resolve the issue. I resolved it by actually hovering/moving my mouse pointer over the R and clicking on Fix Project Properties, you might want to give it a try

Comment: My Bad :/ Sorry All i just Noticed "Android SDK-Build Tools" isnt Installed as @Ken Wolf & CRUSADER Said ill try to Install it Now ...

Comment: Problem Fixed :) , Thanks All & Stack Overflow for your Help especially @Kev Wolf & CRUSADER , My Problem is that i have Updated Everything somes days ago & "Android SDK-Build Tools" was Not Installed