# Import an Android Project from Eclipse to Android Studio and I have this error message "failed to find Build Tools revision 8.0.0"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm trying to import an Android Project from Eclipse to Android Studio, in Eclipse I done the step for export, adding the build.gradle  ...  but I have this error message "failed to find Build Tools revision 8.0.0" when I import the project in Android Studio, any ideas?...

Comment: Have you updated your `Android SDK Build-tools`? If not, try updating it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?lq=1

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Thanx for the answer, but the error still ... I update de SDK Build-Tools and update my Android Studio too, but the same error is showing

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle is trying to use Android SDK tools 8 which isn't installed on your machine.
If you look at your build.gradle file you probably have this line `buildToolsVersion "8"`. You want your build.gradle file to point to the Android SDK tools that you currently have installed (preferably the latest). Just open the Android SDK manager and see which tools you have installed and change the `buildToolsVersion "8"` to the right version.