# R cannot be resolved to a variable, but R.java is generated

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I've created an Android Application project and am getting the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable." I've checked my directory, and R.java is present, all the xml files don't seem to have errors, their names don't have capital letters, spaces, or special characters, deleted the "import java.R" line, cleaned, and rebuilt the project, but I've still been getting this error. According to SDK manager, my Android SDK Tools are all up to date. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: android.R could have been imported in in your app's imports. If it is then remove it

Comment: Wasn't sure if I made this clear, but I've already removed those imports. Was there anything else I might've forgotten to do?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?lq=1

Comment: again check it and clean the project in project>>Clean

Comment: Android SDK Build Tools was already installed. android.R isn't imported and I just cleaned it again, but I'm still getting the error. Do I have to do anything else before cleaning and building it?

Answer (score 0):

fix all your errors first then clean and run.check your API right click project> properties > android >check API 17

Comment: Are you talking about errors in my xml files or errors in my project? Because the only errors I have in my project right now are all related to R.java, and I can't run with them still in there. Should I just comment the lines out? And my current API is 17.

Comment: can you provide a printscreen or a copy of you problems?i just want to see them

Comment: The main and only error I'm getting is "R cannot be resolved to a variable". Is there a way for me to put pictures onto stackoverflow?

Comment: use pastebin.com for now

Comment: Here's my source code http://pastebin.com/HhGhKrbs. Is there anything else you'd like to see?

Comment: wait im having lunch can you check all your drawables are they on the correct folder?i'll be back on you after i eat and you post your xml as well because i don't see anything wrong with your code..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1fS9nXiT Here's my activity_manifest.xml and FileExplorer manifest. What should I be looking for with my drawables?

Comment: i was able to run your program even if im missing a row layout. i put a comment on this line   ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
                 setListAdapter(fileList); and i was able to run it maybe your missing something very important.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unfamiliar with using Eclipse in regards to Android app development, where can I find my logcat?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. My logcat is completely blank. Should there be something there?

Comment: you fixed it?you'll find something there if anything is wrong with your project you can see it in the line caused by line..

Comment: I actually haven't done anything yet, and my project's still not running. There may be something wrong with Eclipse, so I think I'll reinstall it and see if I'm still having issues. Thanks for your help!