# Error messages when starting an android application in eclipse on a strange computer

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android program which works fine on my computer, however, on checking on another persons laptop, I get
      R cannot be resolved to a variable
or

```
 the import mypath/R cannot be resolved
```

How can that be?

Besides, I obviously have a styles.xml, which is autogenerated, I never touched it.
However, when starting the project on another computer , I get

```
  Error retrieving parent for item: no resource found that matches Theme.Appcompat.Light
```

Anyone have any idea

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

Comment: As a matter of fact the question you linked solved it.

Answer (score 1):

1.Clean your project
2.Right click your project ->Properties
3.Click ->Java Build Path
4.Click ->Order and Export
5.Click ->Select All
6.Click ->ok

if that is not working 
1.Click ->Project in option menu
2.Check Build Automatically is clicked 
3.Delete R.java file in gen folder 
4.Clean your project

Comment: The trouble might be that I do not have an R.java file in gen folder. However I have now reproduced the mistake on my own computer - by updating the minimal sdk from 8 to 13. Any suggestionsß

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16608570/2182525 try this update your SDK Build Tool then restart