# R file missing from my android project

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I don't why the hell is R file getting lost. Everytime I build my project everything is fine. Sometimes I get errors while running my android project and sometimes my Eclipse gets crashed. At this situation when I restart eclipse my project will show compilation errors. Even after solving those things, When I build my project the R file is getting lost exactly at that time. And even if I import the R file the errors will move to the next variable. Is there any way to recover the R file or to protect it from getting lost???????

Comment: Its definitely problem in your xml layout. That's why it error occur. Please double check your layout file.

Comment: from where you are importing R file?

Comment: @Sam I think R file generated by android it self. where you from?

Comment: @Sam R file automatically generated by project it self. No need to import it

Comment: `R.java` is regenerated from resources on each build. If you have errors in a resource or in your manifest, that will prevent `R.java` from being rebuilt. You cannot "recover" or "protect" `R.java`, but you can fix whatever problems there are in your resources or manifest. You may also wish to switch to an IDE that has a supported path for Android work. Google has dropped Eclipse support, and [Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore) is still a work in progress. Consider Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA. As a bonus, they provide better error information for this problem.

Comment: Yes, R file will be generated automatically by android itself. And I found another problem. My xml layout file's Graphical Layout view is disabled and I don't know how to enable it :(

Comment: Just try to use different API level for UI rendering.

Comment: try to **clean**  your project and  **re-bulid**  your project...just check your .XML files code or drawable folder file name properly written.

Comment: Actually I am new to android and the bad thing is my system configuration is low to work with android stduio. Thank you all for your support :) and I will be happy if there is any other solution.

Comment: @Darshak, Yes I even tried that but that did'nt help. UI rendereing is also disabled :(

Comment: @VivekaPatel I tried do that everytime I update code in my project, sometimes at this point the R file is getting lost.

Comment: check your update in SDK manager...
[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update)

Comment: @Joshua what have make last changes into the resources. Have you added any drawable or changes in style or any layout xml changes? because this will cause you the R missing error.

Comment: @VivekaPatel Everything is up to date except one file which is Android SDK Tools under Tools (Preview Chennel). Whenever I try to update it its showing some error and the update gets terminated.

Comment: @CreativeAndroid I have not made any changes style or layout and I have not added any drawable but still the R file is getting lost.

Comment: Even when I create a new layout file the Graphical Layout is disabled and I am not able to perform any UI rendering only the Pallete options are available

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens when you have an error in one of your xml files.Another possible reason is that you initially wanted to have your R class not in the default place where it is created but in your own package. So it is possible that R is created in its default location and your program is looking for it somewhere else.

Comment: Actually in code level there is no error in the xml files, the only problem with the xml file is that the Graphical Layout is disabled i.e I cannot perform any UI rendering and I am not getting any layout visually although the layout is declared and defined in code.

Comment: Today I noticed I thing. The xml file in the layout does'nt show error externally. When I was just surfing through it I found a Tab named ERROR LOG. Only in that Tab all the internal errors are visible and Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

if your project R file not generated automatically then this are the possibility i mention below.

- If the R .* can not be generate means that you have some issue into the res/ folder. Check for errors in res/ folder.
- Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
  all the res/* filename should be named with lowercase character, underscore and number between 0 and 9
- Go to Project and hit Clean. This should, among others, regenerate your R.java file.
- Also get rid of any import android.R.* statements and then do the clean up I mentioned.
- Check your latest updates in SDK manager if possible some remain to update.
- Also check target build was set to Android 2.1 (SDK v7) where his layout XML used Android 2.2 (SDK v8) elements (layout parameter match_parent), due to this there was no way for Eclipse to correctly generate the R.java file which caused all the problems.

Comment: You did not get my question properly. The R file is Generating fine in the beginning. When I do changes in my code and when I perform many clean and build operations, suddenly the R file will get lost. I dont know how and why it is happening.

Comment: Today I noticed I thing. The xml file in the layout does'nt show error externally. When I was just surfing through it I found a Tab named ERROR LOG. Only in that Tab all the internal errors are visible and Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve it :(